# Mulesoft Encoded URL not working

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a GET that works perfectly fine in POSTMan

https://server/api/now/table/x_fmc_fss_antenna_site?sysparm_query=sys_created_on%3E2017

But the exact same query in Mulesoft returns an empty result

[image]

```
        <http:request config-ref="SNget" path="/api/now/table/x_fmc_fss_antenna_site" method="GET" doc:name="GET-SN-DATA">
            <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="sysparm_query" value="#[java.net.URLEncoder.encode('sys_created_on&gt;2017','UTF-8')] "/>
            </http:request-builder>
        </http:request>
```

I know the connectivity is working because if I remove the parameter then request works properly. Also if I pick another parameter which doesn't require encoding it works. So it must be something with the encoding I just can't figure it out. I must be missing something basic

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me... No URLEncoder needed

```
    <http:request-builder>
        <http:query-param paramName="sysparm_query" value="sys_created_on&gt;2018"/>
    </http:request-builder>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with the only parameter by removing the URL. Since mule generate the URL one